# In Bash, How To Sort Echo Output from JQ?

Tags: json, bash, shell

I want to make automatic script to parse JSON for some value and `echo`-ing it to somewhere (in this case of test, terminal). Here is my *complicated* code:

```
for ((i = 0 ; i < 34 ; i++)); do
    echo " \
        $(curl -s https://data.covid19.go.id/public/api/prov.json | jq -r ".list_data[$i] .key"):  \ # ex. Output: DKI Jakarta
        $(curl -s https://data.covid19.go.id/public/api/prov.json | jq -r ".list_data[$i] .jumlah_kasus")"; # ex. Output: 580584
done
```

With this loop I got 34 lines:

```
DKI JAKARTA:  580584
JAWA BARAT:  402548
JAWA TENGAH:  265345
JAWA TIMUR:  178799
KALIMANTAN TIMUR:  79876
RIAU:  72361
SULAWESI SELATAN:  65330
DAERAH ISTIMEWA YOGYAKARTA:  65265
BANTEN:  59091
SUMATERA BARAT:  53125
BALI:  51499
SUMATERA UTARA:  36854
KALIMANTAN SELATAN:  36645
SUMATERA SELATAN:  29725
KEPULAUAN RIAU:  27854
KALIMANTAN TENGAH:  26719
LAMPUNG:  22731
KEPULAUAN BANGKA BELITUNG:  21976
PAPUA:  21150
NUSA TENGGARA TIMUR:  19977
ACEH:  19577
SULAWESI UTARA:  16633
KALIMANTAN BARAT:  15585
SULAWESI TENGAH:  13977
KALIMANTAN UTARA:  13466
JAMBI:  13332
NUSA TENGGARA BARAT:  13197
SULAWESI TENGGARA:  11948
PAPUA BARAT:  11682
BENGKULU:  10778
MALUKU:  9067
SULAWESI BARAT:  6043
GORONTALO:  5913
MALUKU UTARA:  5828
```

My question is: **How can I sort the lines alphabetically with keeping province name and value synced?**

E.g. like this:

```
ACEH:  19577
BALI:  51499
# etc...
```

Any answer will be appreciated, thank you. Let me know if there are something unclear so I can explain it.

Comment: To avoid querying in the loop, because the url doesn'tchange. A temporary file can be used instead:
`curl .. > tmp_file; for ..; jq .. -r < tmp_file ..`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you expected :

```
curl -s https://data.covid19.go.id/public/api/prov.json |\
    jq -r '.list_data|sort_by(.key)[]|"\(.key): \(.jumlah_kasus)"'
```

Comment: Waahoo! Yup, this is what I want. Simpler syntax and sorted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Output stuff as one line with unique separator, sort, then replace that separtor with a newline.

```
for ...; do
   echo "$(one)!$(two)"
done | sort | tr '!' '\n'
```